# How to send custom error message to user in node.js + ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, error-handling

Can someone help me with sending an error message from the server to client side via ajax? For example, if my server side returns a 404 error, I want it to also send a custom message: 'something is wrong'

server.js

```
api.get('/api/some_route', function(req, res, next) {

    res.sendStatus(404, 'something is wrong');

});
```

client.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(data, status) {
        console.log(status);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus) //returns error
        console.log(errorThrown) //returns bad request
        //I want to someohow print the 'something is wrong' message from the api
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to call the status method before calling `send` or `json`:

```
res.status(404).send({ error: "Something is wrong"});
```

Comment: I tried this. Still it is goes in ajax success. How can I throw it in ajax error?